# HDD healthcheck tool bootable from USB stick

Tags: usb, hard-disk

I found a few old SATA HDDs that I would like to use as NAS. Since I haven't been using them for a while I would like to make sure they are healthy (no bad sectors, etc.). I have an old laptop with SATA slot where I could connect each of those disks and run health check. The only part I am missing is health check tool. I imagine I boot it from USB stick. Is there anything like that?